# Mount f2fs sdcard on boot

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, mount

I have a 128 GB microsd and I do not want FAT32 on it. I have MIUI 8 (Android 5.1.1) with 3.10.49 kernel, TWRP 3 and root. For some reason `mount` doesn't work at all, it always produces error `Invalid argument`. I tried replacing it with one from BusyBox but it didn't help. Some forum guys told me that I should add the card to fstab (which AFAIK is located inside boot.img), and edit the config of vold (which is located I have no idea where). Also [this](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config.html). All I understood from there is that there is some `storage_list.xml` and I should edit it. Again, searching through forums led me to this path `framework-res.apk\res\xml\storage_list.xml`.
But still! I have no idea where this framework-res.apk is located and how do I unpack-repack it.
All info that I'm desperately trying to extract from google is outdated or related purely to cyanogen >_< Please give some instructions

Comment: Also, I don't really care if it will be `f2fs`, I just heard that 3.10.* kernels already do support f2fs, but if that's a spoof I'm ok with `ext4` or even `exFAT`